# MongoDB addshard: failed to add 2nd shard

Tags: mongodb, sharding

There are 6 directories, each contains about 1 TB data, they all belong to a database "test"
now, and I want group them in a cluster. I have built the Shardserver and Configserver,  but encounter a problem when adding the 2nd shard to the cluster:

```
db.runCommand({addshard:localhost:27017});
db.runCommand({addshard:localhost:27027});
```

> "errmsg" : "can't add shard
>   localhost:27027 because a local database 'test' exists in another
>   shard0000:localhost:27017"

Dropping the 'test' database can solve this problem, but it is not what I want.

How can I merge the 6 shards (they all have 'test' database, belonging to a single logical database) together?

Comment: you cannot do it by adding existing "parts" of the DB.  The best you can do is mongodump contents of your 2nd and 3rd DBs and mongorestore them into your sharded DB through mongos.

Comment: since there are about 6 TB data, this method may be too slow. is there other solutions ?   Actually all I want is searching the whole DB in one query sentences.  thx

Comment: there isn't another way - basically you have separate databases right now - there is no way to merge them other than ... merging them via data copy.

Answer (score 1):

Use **mongodump** the data on second shard, then drop that database and addShard. After that you can import the dump data using **mongorestore**

Answer (score 0):

Although the error complains about another shard, in my experience `the problem was on the shard that I was adding itself`. If you removed the shard gracefully using `db.adminCommand({ removeShard: "shard0000" })`, then there may be an empty database on the shard you're adding. Removing the database on that shard, resolved the issue, and let me add that shard again.